# Dynamic instance of service/class in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dependency-injection

I am building a file uploader in Angular4.
I need to create a custom object of a file, which has some fields and methods inside, every time a user is dropping/selecting a file.

```
class File {
  public isSent: boolean: false;
  public send() {
    //a http call here
  }

  constructor(
    private http: Http
  )
}
```

The problem is that in component, services are created as singletons so there would be only one instance of file per component. I need multiple instances created dynamically.

I can do something like:

```
let file = new File();
```

however DI doesn't seem to work here properly as I need to use Http module inside the file instance.

how to manage such situation?

What I basically need is a simple Class implementation that is using some Angular features (Http) basing on which I would create objects.
Then, in view, I could just bind `file.send()` to a button.

Just to clarify that it's not a duplicate: 
I don't want to inject multiple instances by DI in constructor. I want to create it dynamically on user action.

Comment: If this doesn't answer your question leave a comment. My "powers" ;-) immediately close a question when I vote for duplicate, with lower reps, it needs 5 votes to be actually closed ...

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I saw this thread and actually it's a different case. The topic you provided injects  instances of a services on initialisation. I need to create it dynamically on user action. I don't know how many instances I need on component creation so I can't inject it it that way in constructor. I added a clarification to the description.

Comment: No, it injects a function, that, when you call it, every time returns a new instance (`editorServiceFactory(1);`)

Comment: You may be right. I'll check this out. Thanks